# Flex application doesn't work properly after uploading to a server

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flashdevelop

I'm a C++ programmer, but I'm a newbie in Flex. I'm developing a Flex 3 application for a social network using the FlashDevelop. For debugging I'm using the stand-alone FlashPlayer (10.3 debug) downloaded from Adobe. The application is a simple audio player which shows artist/album images.

The application worked properly on both local computer and remote server until I made some layout changes in Main.mxml. I added some HBoxes and changed Image placement. After that the application still works on my local computer, but it doesn't work properly after I upload it to a server.

Application buttons are not highlighted on over/out/click events, images loaded from the Internet are not displayed, text changed dynamically is not displayed, but when I click buttons a sound file is loaded from the internet and starts playing. It looks like some events which are responsible for components displaying are not dispatched, because some part of functionality not related to displaying still works.

To make sure that this is not a server problem, I rolled back to the previous revision. All works fine.

I suppose that this is a known issue, but I have no idea what is the reason.

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue?
Thanks.

UDP: I observed the issue in IE and FF, I didn't test Opera and Chrome.

Comment: Ish.  There's too many things that can be the problem in this case.  I recommend you use Firebug on FF and check out the network back and forth.

Comment: @Roman not really an answer to your question but you might want to consider using Flex 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you tying to access the pixel data of the images in the new version? If so, that might be the problem, as pixel data for loaded images is not (always) accessible so that might throw a security error, which in turns breaks the rest of the interface.

Also, did you try running the remote version in the debugger? If so, is there any exception being thrown?

And no, it's not a known issue, it's the kind of annoying and hard to debug error that you sometime get when using the Flex SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I'm not trying to access pixel data, just changing Image.src. On the other hand I set smoothBitmapContent="true" for an Image. Can it be the reason?

Comment: Yes that could be the reason. When you set smoothBitmapContent to true, the image component needs to access the pixel data.

Comment: Yes, the reason was smoothBitmapContent. Thanks a lot for helping me.